# Why does my Android app stop just after starting in the Xamarin Android emulator?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I've learned, buy two days of trial and error, that it is safer to start the emulator first, then start the app for debugging. I do that, and all looks good, and my app starts up on the emulator, and after about one second, it stops again.

In the output window, under Xamarin Diagnostics, I see near the bottom:

```
emulator-5554 am force-stop PhoneWord.PhoneWord
```

Why does it force stop the app? I see no errors anywhere, and I somehow had the app working on another emulator yesterday, and I haven't changed anything. Yesterday's emulator just stopped working is all.

Comment: Check your logcat window (not the output window) and ensure that the correct device is selected. Start your app and you should be able to locate the exception.

Comment: @DilbertDave The emulator Just needed more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all such errors have to do with build options.  One such scenario is when your emulator image architecture (x86 or x86_64) is not among the supported architecture on the Android project's properties -> Build Options -> Advanced tab.

Other causes include shared mono framework, low memory etc.